# Best way to mirror an NTFS directory structure (Linux or Windows)

Tags: windows, ntfs

I am trying to mirror a directory structure onto another disk.  The problem with built in tools like RoboCopy is that they get into an infinate loop with the symlinks (think the Users folder).

I would like a utility that safely mirrors the source to the dest while leaving all symlinks in place.

Comment: The `/SL` flag in robocopy makes it copy the actual link and not the target, so that would fix the issue in Windows...

Comment: But it still follows the link

Comment: Why would you be mirroring the `users` folder(s) in Windows elsewhere?

Comment: Because that is the easiest example to use.  Other folders do the same thing.  I am cloning a source disk to a destination disk but I do not want to do a block level copy.  I simply want to copy directory\file structure 1 to 1

Comment: In Windows at least you'll run into issues in the `users` directory is why I ask.  The `/xj` switch in Robocopy takes care of this, but if you want a "clone" you should simply do a block level copy.

Comment: why?  That means I have to waste time copying a ton of free space for no reason.  The way you "clone" in OSX is a file system level copy.  You can even clone linux installations this way.

Comment: Also /xj totally skips creating the junctions so they are not even there